# Capturing page resources (css, js, images) using Selenium 2 in IE

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium 2 (in IE only) and I need to capture all page resources (js, css, images files etc.) and their HTTP status.
I tried to use HTTP analyzer for this but this tool is very unstable and crashes all the time.
Could you please advise how I can resolve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use a proxy to do something like this.  Selenium does not intercept HTTP traffic so cannot do this itself (There is an old capturenetworktraffic implementation in Selenium 1 but that was using some FireFox specific code and did not work for any other browsers).

To configure it:

```
 Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
 proxy.setHttpProxy(<proxyAddress>);
 DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
 cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
 WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(cap);
```

This should enable you to capture network traffic and as a result capture http status codes of various page resources.

Comment: Thanks you. I found a great presentation related to this post - http://www.slideshare.net/watsonmw/performance-monitoring-in-a-day. BTW, I included FiddlerCore in my project.

Comment: If the answer was what you were looking for please mark it as the correct answer so others know that it solved your problem.